# How I can use php if statment in wordpress shortcode?

Tags: php, if-statement, shortcode

I will try to make a WordPress plugin. My all code is ok but I can't understand how I use if else statement in custom post shortcode.

```
global $post;
        $accordion_icon = get_post_meta($idd, 'accordion_icon', true);

        $list .= '
                <div class="collapse-card">
                <div class="title">
                    <i class="fa '.$accordion_icon.' fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                    <strong>'.get_the_title().'</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="body">
                    <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                ';
```

It's my present code. Hear have a icon option in title div .I will want to when I put any custom icon code then show the custom icon and when I don't put any custom icon code then show a common icon. I can understand here need to use if else statement but I don't understand how I use if else statement in my code.

```
$list .= '
                <div class="collapse-card">
                <div class="title">
                '<?php if($accordion_icon) : ?>'
                    <i class="fa '.$accordion_icon.' fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                '<?php else : ?>'
                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                '<?php endif; ?>'

                    <strong>'.get_the_title().'</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="body">
                    <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                ';
```

I used like that but it's not working.Show error .

So now how I can use if else statement ?

Comment: If ($something){do something}; else {} thats the way you should do it i think.

Comment: I will with this type but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either like this (short way):

```
$list .= '<div class="collapse-card">
          <div class="title">';
if($accordion_icon)
    $list .= '<i class="fa '.$accordion_icon.' fa-2x fa-fw"></i>">';
else
    $list .= '<i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x fa-fw"></i>';
```

Or like this (long way):

```
$list .= '<div class="collapse-card">
          <div class="title">';
if($accordion_icon){
    $list .= '<i class="fa '.$accordion_icon.' fa-2x fa-fw"></i>">';
}else{
    $list .= '<i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x fa-fw"></i>';
}
```

*Note: You can only use the short way for 1 line. If your body statement exceeds 1 line you require the curly braces.*

You can also used something called the [coditional operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_conditional_operator_examples.htm), but I don't think that's what you're looking for, for now.

Comment: Glad I could help. Dont forget to accept as answer ;) (click the checkmark left of my answer)